# Is there a way to have sub-objects within an object?

Tags: inkscape, fill

Say I have a rectangle and want to split it to 4 shapes:

[image]

I want to have the middle point be not fixed, and hence the shape of the sub-objects be flexible. If I move the middle point, then the sub-objects should be changed. For now the colors are just bucket filled, which are just 4 new objects.

[image]

Comment: Maybe related: https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/138444/why-does-join-selected-nodes-into-a-single-node-not-work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

1. A rectangle is drawn, Path > Object to Path is applied to get a proper path with nodes at the corners
2. A triangle is drawn with the Bezier tool (=the Pen). It snaps exactly if you have snaps to nodes ON.
3. Two more triangles are drawn
4. All is selected (see NOTE1) and the midpoint nodes are selected by dragging with the node tool over them. Then the selected nodes are moved together with the node tool.

NOTE1: In Inkscape you must at first select the parts with the normal selection tool to be sure the node tool takes all nodes in the same place when you drag a selection rectangle with the node tool.

[image]

ADD: Thanks to user Billy Kerr for inserting this animation.

To make the same with curved part seams probably needs something else. But if there's only the midpoint node and nodes in the corners of the rectangle it works. In the next image the parts have hefty overlaps to avoid gaps when the midpoint is moved:

[image]

If it happens that you need a way to unite or bind together the parts so that they keep their colors and you can move the midpoint by moving one single item without causing gaps, not several simultaneously selected nodes, you want something that Inkscape doesn't have. CAD software and advanced animation software have "constraints" which keep things together.

Another way is to use some geometric deformation and adjust it to get apparent midpoint movement. I must skip these subjects due missing advanced animation or pro level parametric CAD software and actual skills how to use them.

But one "move only single item" version is possible in elementary way also in entry level freeware CAD. It's "Move the top vertex of a 3D four side colored pyramide":

[image]

The pyramide is a 3D solid, it's not separate paths like the triangles in the Inkscape version. Top view makes it look planar:

[image]

Comment: Perhaps you want to use this answer to answer this question as well: [Why does “join selected nodes” into a single node not work?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/138444/26474)

Comment: Programs which are based on Bezier curves do not have branching paths. Every node is an endpoint of one path or an intermediate point of one path. That'a said more than once in answers and comments. I inserted one alternative to my answer.

Comment: @user287001 thats not 100% correct they could have. But the standard drawing formats, eps, svg and pdf do not support them. The standards are more concerned with drawing than having total modeling freedom. So it only implements things needed for drawing and not anything more. The end application can allow as much modeling as you want. But that would neccesitate a new format. Since most 2D drawing applications are direct modelers you dont get this (if they were indirect you would call them 2D modelers). This would lock you the user to the platform too.

Answer (score 0):

Note for the future:

Inkscape 1.1 will have a 'Slice' Live path effect for this.

[image]